# How to read PDFs with Instapaper?

Tags: instapaper

Instapaper currently does not support PDF files, [says official support](http://www.instapaper.com/support).

But is there a way to easily convert a PDF to a "public" HTML file so that it is readable on Instapaper?

Is there another way to access PDFs on Instapaper?

Answer (score 3):

1. Convert PDF to HTML using [IDR Solutions PDF Converter](https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter/)
2. Click "View Online"
3. Use the Instapaper bookmarklet to save the PDF to your Instapaper account

Warning: This works, but not perfectly as formatting can get a little screwy.

FWIW, I also tried downloading the raw HTML and [pasting it into Glitch](https://magnificent-lamp.glitch.me), but the PDF character count is like 20k, and the Glitch server timed out. Also, I'm not sure that Instapaper works on Glitch.me websites.

If you know of a better solution, please lemme know.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [Adobe's online PDF -> Word converter](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/pdf-to-word.html), and then paste the text into an email and send that to [your private Instapaper email address](https://www.instapaper.com/save/email).